# Error C2664 : cannot convert argument 14 from 'CvTermCriteria' to 'int' stereofunctions,cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, stereo-3d, measure

I try to compile stereofunctions.cpp for my stereo vision project and I got this error.
Could anyone help me?

[This is the image of error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2m3n.jpg)

```
error C2664: 'double cvStereoCalibrate(const CvMat *,const CvMat *,const CvMat *,const CvMat *,CvMat *,CvMat *,CvMat *,CvMat *,CvSize,CvMat *,CvMat *,CvMat *,CvMat *,int,CvTermCriteria)' : cannot convert argument 14 from 'CvTermCriteria' to 'int'
```

**This is the source code of stereofunctions.cpp**

```
    //--------------Compute for calibration-------------------
    N = n_boards*n;
    objectPoints.resize(N);
    for( i = 0; i < ny; i++ )
        for(j = 0; j < nx; j++ )   objectPoints[i*nx + j] = cvPoint3D32f(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, 0);
    for( i = 1; i < n_boards; i++ ) copy( objectPoints.begin(), objectPoints.begin() + n, objectPoints.begin() + i*n );
    npoints.resize(n_boards,n);

    CvMat _objectPoints = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &objectPoints[0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0] );
    CvMat _npoints = cvMat(1, npoints.size(), CV_32S, &npoints[0] );
    cvSetIdentity(&_M1calib);
    cvSetIdentity(&_M2calib);
    cvZero(&_D1);
    cvZero(&_D2);

    printf("\nRunning stereo calibration ...");
    fflush(stdout);
    cvStereoCalibrate( &_objectPoints, &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints2, &_npoints,&_M1calib, &_D1, &_M2calib, &_D2,imageSize, &_R, &_Tcalib, &_E, &_F, 
    cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
    CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO+CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH );


    printf("\nDone Calibration");

cvUndistortPoints( &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints1,&_M1calib, &_D1, 0, &_M1calib );
    cvUndistortPoints( &_imagePoints2, &_imagePoints2,&_M2calib, &_D2, 0, &_M2calib );

    CvMat* mx1calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );
    CvMat* my1calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );
    CvMat* mx2calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );
    CvMat* my2calib = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,imageSize.width, CV_32F );

    double R1[3][3], R2[3][3], P1[3][4], P2[3][4];
    CvMat _R1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R1);
    CvMat _R2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R2);

        CvMat _P1 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P1);
        CvMat _P2 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P2);
        cvStereoRectify( &_M1calib, &_M2calib, &_D1, &_D2, imageSize,&_R, &_Tcalib,&_R1, &_R2, &_P1, &_P2, &_Qcalib,0/*CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY*/ );

        cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M1calib,&_D1,&_R1,&_P1,mx1calib,my1calib);
        cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M2calib,&_D2,&_R2,&_P2,mx2calib,my2calib);
```

here the complete source code:

[stereofunctions.cpp in dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4beuijrp9ezb2l/StereoFunctions.cpp?dl=0)

**Thank you**

Comment: According to the docs, the last two parameters (14 and 15) should be `CvTermCriteria` and `int` (in that order), but according to your error message, they are somehow switched. Could something be wrong with your OpenCV header files? Which version are you using?

Comment: Is there any possibility that I need other header? Cause I try to match the parameter and its still error. I use OpenCV 3.0 and VS 2013.

Comment: I was looking at the docs for version 2.x. It seems that indeed the order of argument 14 and 15 was switched between versions 2 and 3. What happens when you switch the order in your call to the function?

Comment: You mean my program made for version 2.x, so thats why I got error when compile it in version 3.0? And could you give me suggestion about what should I do next? I'm so new with OpenCV and need to learn more. Thanks

Comment: Well, if your code was written for 2.x, you should compile it with 2.x. If you want to compile it with 3.x, it might be sufficient to swap the arguments 14 and 15 in the call to `cvStereoCalibrate`, but it might well be that other incompatible changes happened there (why else would they change the order?).